# Conditionally defining the constructor of a template class, based on the template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have the follow class, used as a generic "Point/vector in 2D/3D/etc space":

```
template<size_t dimension>
class Vector
{
private:
    std:array<float, dimension> data;
public:
    //common vector operations etc
    inline float magnitude() const;
    inline Vector<dimension> normalized() const;
    inline static float dotProduct(const Vector<dimension>& left, const Vector<dimension>& right);

    //vector arithmetic operators etc
    inline Vector<dimension> &operator+=(const Vector<dimension> &other);
    inline Vector<dimension> &operator*=(float s);
}
```

There are way more operators and such on this class, but I omitted most of them for brevity. My question is, how can I define the constructor for this class?

When dimension is 2, I want a constructor that takes 2 arguments:

`Vector<2>::Vector(float x, float y) : data({x,y}) {}`

When dimension is 3, I want a constructor that takes 3 arguments:

`Vector<3>::Vector(float x, float y, float z) : data({x,y,z}) {}`

By design, this class supports arbitrary dimensions, so creating a specialization for each dimension isn't an attractive approach, neither is defining a SFINAE-enabled constructor for each supported dimension. How can I write a single constructor for `Vector<N>` that takes in N arguments and passes them as an initializer list to the data array?

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)?

Comment: Yes. I tried having a constructor that takes in a universal reference and forwards it to the data array, and that worked, but the compiler errors when you get the number of arguments wrong were atrocious. I tried explicitly taking in an initializer_list and initializing the data array with this, but then you lose any compile-time guarantees that the initializer list is the correct size. If there's a better technique that I'm aware of I'd be glad to consider it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
template <typename ...Args,
    typename std::enable_if_t<dimension == sizeof...(Args), int> = 0>
    Vector(Args&& ...args) : data { std::forward<Args>(args)... }
{ }

template <typename ...Args,
    typename std::enable_if_t<dimension != sizeof...(Args), int> = 0>
    Vector(Args&& ...args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == dimension, "Dimension doesn't match parameter count");
}
```

Comment: Very good, but don't use `static_assert(false,...)`. It always fails, even when it shouldn't. At least in my compiler and coliru's gcc and clang. Make the condition something it has to instantiate the template to see.

Comment: The second one is still ill-formed NDR, because no valid specialization can be generated for it, even though current compilers are not sufficiently clever to diagnose it.

Comment: I like this answer because of its brevity. The other answers I'm sure do the job just as well, but a reader of my class will understand this code in seconds. As James Root points out, this means we don't get meaningful autocomplete from IDEs, but given that the programmer JUST typed Vector<2> or Vector<6> or whatever, and all the arguments are the same type, and intuitive/obvious, I think it's ok in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Have a few tag types.  First, a `private_tag`.  Second a `count_tag<N>`.

Have a variaridic ctor that takes `T0` and `Ts`.  It sfinae-prevents T0 from being a `private_tag`, then forwards its arguments to the ctor `Vector(private_tag{}. count_tag<sizeof...(Ts)+1>{}, t0, ts...)`.

You can now make a private ctor that first takes private tag, then then the proper count tag, and constructs your array.

Errors will mention being unable to convert the count tags.

The private tag trick error messages can be made better by using a base class for storage, and still constructing it with the count tag.

---

A second approach is to use a static assert.  In order to hit it before you hit the ctor for the array, you'll want to use some tricks, like an empty base class that takes `Ts&&` and has the static assert in its body (but does nothing else).

---

If you do not mind accepting 2 elements for a vector of size 3, have a `std::array<float,3>` ctor.

---

Synthesize a `std::tuple<float,float,float>` type for a vector 3, then have that ctor.  With c++17 you get `MyVec({3.14f, 0f, 2f})`,mand in C++11 you need to `MyVec(std::make_tuple(3.14, 0, 2))`, but it otherwise works well.  Punt the job to tuple.  You can also write a custom type in C++11 with the requisite implicit ctormto give you the nice C++17 syntax.

Like this:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
```

Useful boilerplate.  Then:

```
template<template<class...>class Z, size_t N, class T>
struct repeat;
```

Repeat takes a template a count and a type, and repeats the type count times passing them to the template.

```
template<template<class...>class Z, size_t N, class T>
using repeat_t=type_t<repeat<Z,N,T>>;
```

Which gives us `ntuple`, which takes a type and a count, and returns a tuple:

```
template<size_t N, class T>
using ntuple=repeat_t<std::tuple, N, T>;
```

There are many ways to write repeat.  Here is an easy way:

```
namespace details{
  template<template<class...>class Z, class Ns, class T>
  struct repeat;
  template<std::size_t, class T>using the_T=T;
  template<template<class...>class Z, std::size_t...Ns, class T>
  struct repeat<Z,std::index_sequence<Ns...>,T>:
    tag<Z< the_T<Ns, T>... >>
  {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, size_t N, class T>
struct repeat:
  details::repeat<Z, std::make_index_sequence<N>, T>
{};
```

and done.  If you lack index sequence support, there are many high quality implementations on SO.  Look for one with log recursive depth.

Comment: Is it possible to make a template typedef or something, so that `MyTuple<float, 4>` resolves to `std::tuple<float,float,float,float>` ?

Comment: Now that major compilers are moving towards intrinsic-based `make_integer_sequence` implementations, I'd just use it.

Comment: @t.c. d'oh, ya, that is much cleaner.  And if we are gonna hand write it, do the log depth mess *there* instead of here.

Answer (score 2):

Both Clang and MSVC are, or will soon be, implementing `std::make_integer_sequence` with an intrinsic, and GCC/libstdc++ now has a O(log N) library-based implementation, so let's not reinvent the wheel of "how do I get a pack of a particular size". Build an index sequence, and generate the desired list of types by pack expansion with an alias template.

```
template<size_t dimension,
         class IndexSeq = std::make_index_sequence<dimension>>
class VectorStorage;

template<size_t dimension, size_t... Is>
class VectorStorage<dimension, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template<size_t> using ElementType = float;
protected:
    std:array<float, dimension> data;
public:
    VectorStorage() = default;
    VectorStorage(ElementType<Is>... args) : data{args...} {}
 };

template<size_t dimension>
class Vector : VectorStorage<dimension>
{
public:
    using VectorStorage<dimension>::VectorStorage;
    // other stuff

};
```

Comment: A quick google search for this turns up nothing. Do you know where I can find documentation for this?

Comment: @Elliott What is "this"? `make_integer_sequence`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution makes the design uglier, but it provides the constructor you want.

```
template <typename... Ts_>
class VectorCtor //Hold the array and provide the ctor for Vector
{
protected:
    std::array<float, sizeof...(Ts_)> _data;
public: //I can't find a way to make this protected otherwise I would
    VectorCtor() = default;
    VectorCtor(const VectorCtor&) = default;
    VectorCtor(Ts_... args) : _data{ args... } {}
};

template <std::size_t X_, typename... Ts_>
struct MakeCtor //Recursively adds floats to Ts_
{
    typedef typename MakeCtor<X_ - 1, Ts_..., float>::type type;
};
template <typename... Ts_>
struct MakeCtor<0, Ts_...> //Base case
{
    typedef VectorCtor<Ts_...> type;
};

template <std::size_t N_>
class Vector : public MakeCtor<N_>::type //Gets parent type for ctor
{
    typedef typename MakeCtor<N_>::type Parent;
public:
    using Parent::Parent; //Use parent class constructors
    //... the rest of it
};
```

`Vector` derives from a `VectorCtor` class and uses it's constructors. A `Vector<2>` will have `VectorCtor<float, float>` as a parent, and inherit the `VectorCtor(float, float)` constructor. The `MakeCtor` class just converts the dimensions of the `Vector` into the correct number of `float` arguments through template recursion.

I prefer functions with a set signature over variadic ones that fail when the wrong arguments are passed. This way, in Visual Studio at least, I can see the signature as I'm typing, and IntelliSense will highlight when I have the wrong number of arguments.

**UPDATE:** So, down the rabbit hole a little. As @Yakk has informed me, the template recursion will slow down the build and crash when the size is too large. For my compiler, the default upper limit is about 500. An array larger than that won't compile.

```
fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex
```

I wasn't sure how to implement binary recursion for a template like this, so I guesstimated until something worked. This can definitely handle larger sizes, at least.

```
template <typename T_, std::size_t N_>
struct Node{}; //Hold type and recursion depth data

template <typename... Ts_>
struct Wrap //Hold list of types
{
    typedef Wrap<Ts_...> type;
};

template <typename... W1_, typename... W2_, typename... Ts_>
struct Wrap<Wrap<W1_...>, Wrap<W2_...>, Ts_...> //Two Wraps combine to a single Wrap
{
    typedef Wrap<W1_..., W2_..., Ts_...> type;
};

template <typename, typename>
struct Join;

template <typename>
struct Split;

template <typename T_, std::size_t N_>
struct Split<Node<T_, N_>> //Make two Nodes with size N_ / 2
{
    typedef typename Wrap<typename Split<Node<T_, N_ / 2>>::type, typename Split<Node<T_, N_ - N_ / 2>>::type>::type type;
};
template <typename T_>
struct Split<Node<T_, 1>> //Base case
{
    typedef Wrap<T_> type;
};

template <typename>
struct Get;

template <typename... Ts_>
struct Get<Wrap<Ts_...>> //Retrieve
{
    typedef VectorCtor<Ts_...> type;
};

template <typename T_, std::size_t N_>
struct Expand //Interface to start recursion
{
    static_assert(N_ > 0, "Size cannot be zero!");
    typedef typename Get<typename Split<Node<T_, N_>>::type>::type type;
};

template <typename T_, std::size_t N_>
using BaseType = typename Expand<T_, N_>::type; //Less typing
```

`Vector` just needs a minor change:

```
template <std::size_t N_>
class Vector : public BaseType<float, N_> //Change the base class, and typedef too
```

The `Node` struct holds the size, and `Split` recursively splits each `Node` into two `Node`s of half size. This continues until the size is 1, where it becomes the type (`float` here) and then are all put into the `VectorCtor`. My guess is that the limit would now be around 2^500, but if I go much higher than 10,000-ish the compiler runs out of memory. Builds of that size are VERY slow, but a reasonable size of, say, 1024 seems fine.

Comment: Note that the linear recursion above will break your build speeds above a few dozen, and break the build above a few hundred.  Modify it to binary recursion and you'll get a faster build time, and a higher count limit.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks, I put another idea in my answer. I hadn't ever tried binary recursion, so I worked out something. Is it sort of what you meant?

Comment: It is hard the first time!  `template <std::size_t X_, class, typename... Ts_>
struct MakeCtor; //Recursively adds floats to Ts_
{
    typedef typename MakeCtor<X_ - 1, Ts_..., float>::type type;
};